# How to load multiple csv-files into xarray Dataset and concat along multiple dimensions?

Tags: python, dataframe, multidimensional-array, dataset, python-xarray

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65490931/xarray-loading-several-csv-files-into-a-dataset) to mine, but the data has a different structure and I run into errors. I have multiple `.dat` files, that contain tables for different arbitrary times `t=1,3,9,10,12`, etc. The tables in the different `.dat` files have the same columns `M_star, M_planet, separation`, and `M_star` can be viewed as an index in steps of 0.5. Nevertheless, the length of the tables and the values of `M_star` vary from file to file, e.g. for time `t=1` I have

```
M_star M_planet separation
10.0   0.022    7.11
10.5   0.019    2.30
11.0   0.008    14.01
```

while for `t=3` I have

```
M_star M_planet separation
9.5    0.308    1.32
10.0   0.522    4.18
10.5   0.019    3.40
11.0   0.338    0.91
11.5   0.150    1.20
```

What I would like to do is to load all the `.dat` files into an xarray DataSet (at least I think this would be useful), so that I can access data in the columns `M_planet` and `separation` by providing precise values for `t` and `M_star`, e.g. I would like to do something like `ds.sel(t=9, M_star=10.5)['M_planet']` to get the value of `M_planet` at the given `t` and `M_star` coordinates. What I have tried sofar unsuccessfully is:

```
fnames = glob('table_t=*.dat')
fnames.sort()
kw = dict(delim_whitespace=True,names=['M_star', 'M_planet', 'separation'], skiprows=1)

# first I load all the tables into a list of dataframes
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fname,**kw) for fname in fnames]
# then I include as a column to each dataframe the time, all the t-entries are same within a dataframe
dfs2= [df_i.assign(t=t) for df_i, z in zip(dfs, [1,2,3,4,9,10,12])]
# I try to make an array DataSet, but I run into an error
d = xr.concat([df_i.to_xarray() for df_i in df_s2], dim='t')
```

The last line throws an error: `t already exists as coordinate or variable name.`

How can I load my `.dat` files into xarray and make `t` and `M_star` the dimensions/coordinates? Tnx

Comment: If each file has different values of M_star, I don’t think you want it to be a coordinate. Xarray requires the array dimensions to be orthogonal; so creating this array would expand the data to include every combination of t and M_Star. Pandas seems pretty appropriate for this to me, though I don’t know much about your workflow. The narrow issue you’re facing is that t must be a coordinate, not a data variable, on each concatenated dataset, so you should use assign_coords after converting to xarray rather than df.assign.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thank you, I will try to implement your suggestion about assign_coord. The `M_star` column is actually not completely arbitrary, as I stated before, it goes in steps of 0.5, but the number of steps varies in the different files. I corrected my question. Do you see if it might be working with this new information?

Comment: Ok - in that case you’ll still end up with NaNs in your results but maybe you’re fine with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you are assigning `t` as a column in the dataframes, which are converted to data variables in the xarray datasets (indexed only by M_star) so the t values are interpreted as conflicts during the merge.

Additionally, since you’re combining along both M_star and t, you should use [`xr.combine_by_coords`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.combine_by_coords.html#xarray.combine_by_coords) rather than concat, which only works along one dimension. See the [merging and combining data docs](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/combining.html) for an overview of the different options.

You can fix this by making sure t becomes a dimension/coordinate before merging. You could assign it as a dimension right away by adding it to the pandas index rather than the columns:

```py
dfs2 = [
    df_i.assign(t=t).set_index('t', append=True)
    for df_i, z in zip(dfs, [1,2,3,4,9,10,12])
]
```

Alternatively you could move the t coordinate assignment into xarray:

```py
d = xr.combine_by_coords(
    [
        df_i.to_xarray().expand_dims(t=[z])
        for df_i, z in zip(df1, [1,2,3,4,9,10,12]))
    ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks you! I had now the time to test your solution and it does what I want, when I alter you second suggestion to `df_i.set_index('M_star').to_xarray()......` :) Hence, I accept your answer as a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Using Michael Delgado's comments a solution to my problem can be coded that way:

```
fnames = glob('table_t=*.dat')
fnames.sort()
kw = dict(delim_whitespace=True,names=['M_star', 'M_planet', 'separation'], skiprows=1)

# first I load all the tables into a list of dataframes
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fname,**kw) for fname in fnames]

# set_index('M_star') turns M_star from a df-column into an index, as Michael said this is necessary
# expand_dims(t=[t]) turns t into a dim/coordinate of the DataSet, which I also want
d = xr.combine_by_coords(
    [
        df_i.set_index('M_star').to_xarray().expand_dims(t=[t])
        for df_i, t in zip(dfs, [1,2,3,4,9,10,12])
    ],
)
```

With this I have the DataSet `d` in the form that I wanted, both `t` and `M_star` being my coordinates/dimentions, see below (the naming is different):

[image]

This allows me to do what I wanted - access values in the DataSet based on me providing precise values both along `M_star` and `t`:

```
print(float(d.sel(t=9, Log10M_h=11.5)['M_planet'].values))
>>> 0.019
```

But as Michael stated, I can also get an alternative solution by using only a pandas df instead of an array DataSet. For that I concatenate all the dataframes into one long one and I assign and additional column `t` to keep track of this value, I actually don't need `t` to be an index. This is how the alternative using exclusively pandas would look like:

```
# in the 3 lines below we create a df with all the data files concatenated
df_s = [pd.read_csv(fname,**kw) for fname in fnames]
df_s2= [df_i.assign(t=t) for df_i, t in zip(df_s, [1,2,3,4,9,10,12])]
df = pd.concat(df_s2).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df[(df.t==3) & (df.M_star==10.5)]['M_planet'].values[0])
>>> 0.171
```